# Syntax error in activate.bat file during setting venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I`m trying to set up the virtual environment(venv) for python. When I try to activate it with `python activate.bat` I see the error:

```
File "C://Project_X/venv_project/venv/Scripts/activate.bat", line 1
    @echo off
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried:

- to change the path
- re-created the venv
- a lot of search in google

Issue remains. Maybe someone has an idea how to solve it.

Comment: You are not supposed to run it with `python`. Just `activate.bat` should work

Comment: @hansolo Tried it just now. Error: `The term 'activate.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`

Comment: Run it from the command line like any other program. It sounds like you're trying to run it in PowerShell.

Comment: Are you working on Windows ?

Comment: I got this error in comment above, because I tried to execute `activate.bat`. But I should type `./activate.bat`. So now it works for me. Thank you for a help, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python creates the file activate.bat when you use it to create a virtual environment.

just run the

> /Scripts/activate.bat

without python because its for the shell